# No sound in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, kubuntu

I have an [HP EliteBook 8560w](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04151043) with Kubuntu 14.04 and 3.13.0-30 kernel.

Sound is not working. I tried to

- upgrade the system
- reinstall pulseaudio
- add `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

At boot time I get the following errors:

```
genirq: Flags mismatch irq 5. 00000080 (snd_hda_intel) vs. 00000000 (parport0)
hda-intel: unable to grab IRQ 5, disabling device
```

Output of `aplay -l` is

```
 List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

In `alsamixer` the channels are 0 and cannot be modified.

Output of `lsmod` is

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ppp_deflate            12950  0 
bsd_comp               12921  0 
ppp_async              17413  1 
crc_ccitt              12707  1 ppp_async
huawei_cdc_ncm         12966  0 
cdc_wdm                19053  1 huawei_cdc_ncm
cdc_ncm                24511  1 huawei_cdc_ncm
usbnet                 43913  2 huawei_cdc_ncm,cdc_ncm
mii                    13934  1 usbnet
option                 42468  2 
usb_wwan               20429  1 option
usbserial              45014  7 option,usb_wwan
usb_storage            62209  0 
ctr                    13049  0 
ccm                    17773  0 
nvram                  14411  0 
rfcomm                 69160  8 
bnep                   19624  2 
binfmt_misc            17468  1 
btusb                  32412  0 
bluetooth             395423  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
hp_wmi                 14062  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 hp_wmi
mxm_wmi                13021  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46207  4 
intel_rapl             18773  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
coretemp               13435  0 
kvm                   451511  0 
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13216  0 
aesni_intel            55624  0 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
cryptd                 20359  3    ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper                                                                                                                                                                                                    
snd_hda_intel          52355  4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
arc4                   12608  2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
snd_hda_codec         192906  2 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel                                                                                                                                                                                                               
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
iwldvm                232285  0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
mac80211              626557  1 iwldvm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
snd_pcm               102099  3    snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel                                                                                                                                                                                                 
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
snd_seq_midi           13324  0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi                                                                                                                                                                                                                
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi                                                                                                                                                                                                               
joydev                 17381  0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
serio_raw              13462  0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
iwlwifi               169932  1 iwldvm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
nvidia              10675249  51                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
snd                    69238  18 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi                                                                                                                    
cfg80211              484040  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
lpc_ich                21080  0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
drm                   303102  2 nvidia                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
soundcore              12680  1 snd
mei_me                 18627  0 
tpm_infineon           17372  0 
hp_accel               26012  0 
wmi                    19177  2 hp_wmi,mxm_wmi
mei                    82276  1 mei_me
lis3lv02d              20156  1 hp_accel
input_polldev          13896  1 lis3lv02d
mac_hid                13205  0 
parport_pc             32701  1 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
psmouse               102222  0 
ahci                   25819  3 
libahci                32168  1 ahci
firewire_ohci          40409  0 
sdhci_pci              23172  0 
sdhci                  43015  1 sdhci_pci
firewire_core          68769  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              12707  1 firewire_core
e1000e                254433  0 
video                  19476  0 
ptp                    18933  1 e1000e
pps_core               19382  1 ptp
```

There is no hardware problem, the sound works fine in Windows.
Any idea?

Comment: `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` is unlikely to work since you seem to have nvidia hardware... Please post the output of `lsmod`.

Comment: I modified the question and added the output of `lsmod`.

Comment: There are some errors at boot time and I added them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver you added to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` is for *Intel* soundcards. It's perfectly normal that this doesn't work on your system, because the manufacturer of the sound chip is *NVidia*. You computer thus disables the device:

```
genirq: Flags mismatch irq 5. 00000080 (snd_hda_intel) vs. 00000000 (parport0)
hda-intel: unable to grab IRQ 5, disabling device
```

Your list of playback devices also shows *NVidia* hardware.

You need to find and use a driver for your *NVidia* platform.

Comment: I guess that the problem is that the sound card from the video card (HDMI) conflicts with the one from motherboard, which is an Intel one. But I don't know how to disable the one from nVidia video card.

Comment: http://www.linlap.com/hp_elitebook_8560w doesn't mention Intel sound hardware, but HP specs indicate that it has a QM67 chipset. Do you try to get sound from the HDMI cable, speakers or headphone?

Comment: There is no sound from speakers or headphone. I haven't tried HDMI.

Comment: AFAIK sound from the speakers and headphones comes from the intel stuff, NVidia only outputs sound via HDMI. So we need to get your snd_hda_intel up and running. If you don't use the parallel port, disable it in your BIOS and report back.

Comment: If I disable the parallel port in BIOS, the above errors are gone and then I have in `kmix` _Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo_ playback device along with _GF106 High definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI)_. And sound is working.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked out.

Comment: Now, there's a problem if I also want to use the parallel port :).