# Sound Not Working Kubuntu 14.04 kernel 3.13.0-48-generic

Tags: 14.04, sound, kubuntu, alsa

Sound just stopped. Was working for a couple of years.

I get a intel boot up tone. Sound works in windows.

I looked at
[No sound in Kubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524452/no-sound-in-kubuntu-14-04)

Following advice here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo

I've generated info here:
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=537066e2449866f5501ecb9aa8e20cffb4e86bf5

I've purged and reinstalled pulseaudio and alsa a few times in searching for a fix.

Comment: can you boot with a usb bootable ubuntu and verify if the sound works on that?

Comment: I've just downloaded kubuntu 15.04 and will burn it and get back to you. (it's Uefi and don't have a huge amount of success with USB drive multibooting) thanks

Comment: now need to buy a DVD

Comment: well, It was a public holiday, so I went back in the afternoon and bought some dvds. Now K3b doesn't recognise my USB dvd drive, a whole new world of pain.

Comment: okay, burnt the dvd and there were a few issues, such that it's lack of audio seemed minor ( dolphin didn't want to work at all, difficult to find a sound file and the settings GUI made no noise when attempting to fiddle in multimedia, ) very non- responsive from the dvd and it refused to shutdown....

Comment: works fine in Windows

Comment: I've successfully installed Kubuntu 15.04 and sound now works fine, however I will now begin searching for ways to get my old home partition to be my new home partition